# Linear independence of $\{x \cos x, x, \cos x\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

In the vector space of $\{f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}\}$, how do I prove that $\{x \cos x,x, \cos x\}$ are linearly independent (or not)?
It seems if we look on the equation $a(x \cos x) + b (x) + c (\cos x) = 0$
for $a = b = 0, c = 1, \cos x = 0$ for $x= \frac{\pi}{2}$ for example.

Does this imply they are linearly independent?

Comment: Please type your question using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for clarity.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use mathjax to make your question readable. What do you mean with the vector space of 'f: R->R?'. This is a function, not even a set.

Comment: The $=$ sign in  that space is as functions. So, the equality of their values is expected to hold for all $x$. One single $x$ for which the equation of their values holds is not enough.

Comment: And idea is to notice that the assumption that $a(x\cos(x))+bx +c\cos(x)=0$ holding for all $x$ implies that if you take three special values for $x$ you get three equations that $a,b,c$ must satisfy. If you choose well the three values of $x$ you might get a system with non-zero determinant, which implies that the only solution is $a=b=c=0$.

Comment: Another technique, since the vectors are differentiable functions, is to take derivatives. If the equation is to be hold for all $x$, then the equation resulting from taking derivatives also holds. Likewise if you take second derivatives. That would give you three equations again. Its determinant is a function of $x$ called the [Wronskian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian). If the Wronskian happens to be ever non-zero. The only solution for $a,b,c$ is to be zero.

Comment: Which inner product? You can't decide if something is linearly independent if you don't specify inner product.

Comment: @mathreadler [Linear independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence) is a property definable in vector spaces. No inner product needed.

Comment: @mathreadler where did you hear something like that??

Comment: @Omnomnomnom maybe someone lied to me?

Comment: @mathreadler They are related. Inner products defines angles in a vector space, while linear independence can be seen as certain angles being zero. For that reason if there is an inner product defined one can use it to test for linear independence.

Comment: @mathreadler it is worth noting that inner products give an **easy** test for linear independence (essentially for the same reason that orthogonal matrices are easy to invert).

Answer (score 6):

Suppose there exist three reals $a,b,c $ such that for all $x\in \mathbb R $,

$$ax\cos(x)+bx+c\cos (x)=0$$

then if we take $x=0$, we find that
$c=0$

and if $x=\pi/2$, we get
$b=0$

finally, if $x=\pi $, it gives $a=0$.

this proved, the three functions are independent.

Comment: I don't get it. Your examples implies that for the 3 x values you gave the functions are dependent. How does it proves the opposite?

Comment: @notyourbusiness  $a=b=c=0 \implies $ independent.

Comment: @notyourbusiness The first equation has to hold for *all* values of $x$, so we can make clever choices of $x$ to determine what the coefficients $a$, $b$ and $c$ must be.

Answer (score 2):

We must have that $a x \cos x + bx + c \cos x = 0$ **for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$**

Since for $x = \pi/2$, we have $b*\pi/2 = 0$, it follows that $b=0$.  Then, take $x = 0$, it follows that $c = 0$. Ultimately, we have $ax \cos x = 0$, from which follows that $a = 0$ (take for example $x = 2$). Hence, the set of vectors is linearly independent.